# Bash script IF and || creates syntax error

Tags: bash, if-statement, handle

I have a bash script where I wish to write into a file if one of the commands inside an IF statement ends with nonzero (so when it exits with an error). However with the following I get a syntax error with an unexpected "else" at the end. Am I using this error writing right?

```
if [[ $f != */.* ]]; then
        echo "$f"
        command-one || { echo 'Something went wrong with Command-one at file ' $f ' !' >> ../corrupted.txt } || error=1
        command-two || { echo 'Something went wrong with Command-two at file ' $f ' !' >> ../corrupted.txt } || error=1
        command-three || { echo 'Something went wrong with Command-three at file ' $f ' !' >> ../corrupted.txt } || error=1
        if [ error == 0 ]
        then
            echo "====================================================" >> ../ok.txt
            echo "All went well with: " $f >> ../ok.txt
        fi
        error=0
    else
        echo "This file is corrupted: " $f >> ../corrupted.txt
    fi
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you are dealing with here is a classic example of [SC1083 - This {/} is literal. Check expression (missing ;/\n?) or quote it.](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC1083)

`}` is literal because it's not at the start of an expression. We fix it by adding a `;` before it.

so add a `;` just before `}` to indicate command-termination and double-quote all your variables as,

```
command-one || { echo "Something went wrong with Command-one at file  ${f}  !" >> ../corrupted.txt; } || error=1
command-two || { echo "Something went wrong with Command-two at file  ${f}  !" >> ../corrupted.txt; } || error=1
command-three || { echo "Something went wrong with Command-three at file ${f} !" >> ../corrupted.txt; } || error=1
```

Another would be to fix the comparison operator to

```
if [ $error -eq 0 ];
```

Comment: Jesus, I would have never figured this one out on my own. Thank you a lot, it works like a charm now. Please guys upvote this answer because this is a very uncommon thing I assume.

Comment: @Bert: Do use http://www.shellcheck.net/ in the future for fixing trivial syntax bugs, caught yours that way. Also, nobody is perfect. Happy you found it useful.

Answer (score 1):

operators `==` and `!=` are for string comparison only

**From**

```
if [ error == 0 ]
```

**To**

```
if [ $error -eq 0 ]
```

To compare integers you must use those operators (From Man Page):

```
   INTEGER1 -eq INTEGER2
          INTEGER1 is equal to INTEGER2

   INTEGER1 -ge INTEGER2
          INTEGER1 is greater than or equal to INTEGER2

   INTEGER1 -gt INTEGER2
          INTEGER1 is greater than INTEGER2

   INTEGER1 -le INTEGER2
          INTEGER1 is less than or equal to INTEGER2

   INTEGER1 -lt INTEGER2
          INTEGER1 is less than INTEGER2

   INTEGER1 -ne INTEGER2
          INTEGER1 is not equal to INTEGER2
```

and

```
command-one || { echo 'Something went wrong with Command-one at file ' $f ' !' >> ../corrupted.txt && error=1; }
command-two || { echo 'Something went wrong with Command-two at file ' $f ' !' >> ../corrupted.txt && error=1; }
command-three || { echo 'Something went wrong with Command-three at file ' $f ' !' >> ../corrupted.txt  && error=1; }
```

**Explanation**

```
command-one || { echo 'Something went wrong with Command-one at file '$f ' !' >> ../corrupted.txt && error=1; }
```

If `command-one` returns exit code other than 0 then, append text mentioned in `echo` to file `../corrupted.txt` and set variable `error` to 1

Answer (score 0):

You've missed a `;` at the end of `if [ error == 0 ]`

Comment: Included both `;` and `-eq` , but still the same error comes up